# SSIS keyboard shortcut to move to control flow tab or data flow tab

Tags: ssis, shortcut, keystrokes

Now here's a quick question: is there a key to move between the tabs of the package editor in SSIS?  The only site I can find is [this Microsoft one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173782%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and the keyboard shortcut listed there doesn't work in SQL Server Integration Services 2012.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

F8 or Shift-F8 will cycle through the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, menu items **Test** and **SSIS** have the same shortcut 's'.

The simplest way I can think of.

- View Data Flow - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>
- View Control Flow - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Me too!  Not really a shortcut, though ... unless anyone knows better, it looks like you can't do this with a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: So it looks. You can certainly define your own custom shortcut: Tools> Options> Environment> Keyboard.

Comment: That I knew, and may resort to it.  I was mainly asking because I'll be teaching it soon.  Thanks again.